# Where did the LP to BP transformation $ \frac{\omega ^{2}-\omega_0^{2}}{\omega\cdot BW} $ come from?

Tags: filter

I'm not sure this question is appropriate for this site, but I feel that if anyone knows about a filter, a radio ham knows!
And as a ham myself I feel I need to understand this important area better. To that end, I've been reading various filter texts (Zverev and Dimopoulos mainly).

I'm at the point where the low-pass approximation has been developed (I'm going to chose a Butterworth for this question) and I'm moving to the transformation of a low-pass to other types (high-pass, band-pass, etc).

Lets take a Butterworth low-pass given in the book by Dimopoulos:
$$ \frac{17.5514}{s^3+3.2743\cdot s^2+5.3604 \cdot s+4.3878}$$

If you have Maxima installed, you can try it yourself:

```
load(draw);

maxima_tempdir:"C:/maxima-5.41.0a";

H_lpbut(s):=17.5514/(s^3+3.2743*s^2+5.3604*s+4.3878);

G_lp(omega):=abs(subst([s=%i*omega],H_lpbut(s)));

Omega_3dB(N):=(1/beta_m())^(1/N);

draw2d(
        xlabel="Omega" 
        ,ylabel="Lowpass G(Omega)"
        ,xaxis=true
        ,yaxis=true
        ,xrange=[-10,10]
        ,yrange=[0,5]
        ,explicit(G_lp(omega),
                    omega,-10,10
                    )
        ,color=red
        ,points([[Omega_3dB(3), G_lp(Omega_3dB(3))]])
        ,points_joined=true
        ,line_type=dashes
        ,points([
                [0,G_lp(Omega_3dB(3))]
                ,[Omega_3dB(3), G_lp(Omega_3dB(3))]
                ,[Omega_3dB(3), 0]
            ])
    );
```

As you can see, I get the magnitude of the transfer function and plot from the normalized frequencies -10 to 10.  Notice how wonderfully symmetrical the plot is.

[image]

That sort of makes sense, we're plugging in negative frequencies (from -10 to zero) and we end up with a mirror image of the low-pass giving a band-pass shape.

In fact, that's pretty much how the lp to bp transform works, only this time they use a different function:

$$ \frac{\omega ^{2}-\omega_0^{2}}{\omega\cdot BW} $$

Again, using Maxima we can explore how this function maps band-pass frequencies to normalized low-pass frequencies.  I've taken some liberties here to highlight it's properties (it uses a log scale and negative infinity is now positive infinity - but you get the idea).  The function goes to infinity at one end (omega=0) and takes a more leisurely trip to infinity at the other (omega=inf).  It converges at zero (or bp centre frequency), which is exactly what required for bp transformation - so I get that bit.

```
bpt(omega,omega_0,BW):=(omega^2-omega_0^2)/(omega*BW);

draw2d(
        xrange=[0,1000]
        ,yrange=[0.0001,1000]
        ,logy=true
        ,explicit(sqrt(bpt(2*%pi*f,2*%pi*500,2*%pi*100)^2),
                    f,0,1000
                    )
    );
```

[image]

and finally, here's the transformed band-pass using the standard lp-to-bp transform:

[image]

Notice it isn't as symmetrical as the previous plot (using -10 to 10).

**But, here's what I don't get...why would they use a function like this, which is obviously non-symmetrical, to produce the band-pass?  Why not use a function that works to produce the nice linear -10 to 10 input that we saw earlier?**

Comment: Is there actually something (of reasonable order) that produces a symmetrical-looking bandpass response? It's not fair to compare it to a reflection around zero, even your bandpass filter will be symmetrical (with two humps) if you plot from -800 to 800 rad/s.

Comment: I understand that.  The question is an alternative way of asking where the translation function came from.   I offered the argument that you could (at least mathematically) produce a symmetrical BP filter using a simpler (I'm guessing) function.  I acknowledge the translation has meaning and works (of course it does!), I'm simply trying to tease out what that meaning is.

Comment: I'm guessing the translation is designed to produce a response that can be implemented by a real circuit.  But, it would be good to know why it does that.

Comment: This question was asked and answered on [dsp.SE](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/22016/how-is-the-lowpass-to-bandpass-transformation-derived).

Comment: @Brian K1LI, that is a slightly different question.  I don't have a problem understanding how the function creates a bandpass from a lowpass and I think I covered that in my question.  What I'm asking is why this particular *"simple, mathematically continuous mapping"*.  What is it that makes this very geometric looking mapping work better than any others?

Comment: @Brian K1LI actually, in the comments section the respondent does offer a potential clue that I hadn't considered and that is, you **may** end up with this mapping if you multiply a LP and HP together.  But no further information is given.

Comment: Buck8pe, I think you are making this more complicated than it needs to be.  The slope of the curves in the cut-off region are determined by the capacitors and inductors (differentiators and integrators) and as such are constrained to only have certain values.  They cannot be symmetric between 0 and (any positive frequency).  The curves shown are known to work well, but may not be "best"; much work went into them back in the day and there may perhaps still be more to do.

Comment: @Chris K8NVH making things more complicated! Moi! Joking of course. I'll push on and hope that I find some understanding later.

Comment: Suggestion...  your 3rd plot has x axis limits [200, 800]; change that to [-800, 800] and it might be more clear to you what @tomnexus is saying

Comment: I think I'm starting to understand why now.  It's because the centre frequency of a bandpass filter is geometric as opposed to arithmetic.  This mapping produces a geometric mean centre frequency and I think all of this is associated with the filters multiplicative nature LP() * HP().  This was hinted at in the dsp SE answer and the Dimopoulos text actually pointed out that the mapping produced a geometric mean Fc (I just didn't get it at the time).